# foreach statement not returning all values within an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a very simple Array that contains a link, and the link title. When I print the Values, for some reason the "3rd" value is missing. I have double checked to make sure the 3rd value exists, and it does. I do not understand what is happening? Any suggestions would be great!!!

```
<?php

$resources = array(
    "$link" => "$link_name",
    "$link1" => "$link_name1",
    "$link2" => "$link_name2",
    "$link3" => "$link_name3",
    "$link4" => "$link_name4"
);

foreach ($resources as $resources_link => $resources_name) {
    echo "<a href=\"$resources_link\">$resources_name</a><br>";
}
?>
```

The out put looks like: (Missing the 3rd value)
Link1
Link2
Link4
Link5

Comment: What values are in all the variables in your array?

Comment: and why do you need to put your variables in the array in double quotes?

Comment: Are you sure you never passed that array by reference? That would corrupt the array, and you would need to reset() it before your foreach.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code and works perfectly fine:

```
<?php

$link = "www.google.com";
$link_name = "Google";

$link1 = "www.google1.com";
$link_name1 = "Google1";

$link2 = "www.google2.com";
$link_name2 = "Google2";

$link3 = "www.google.com3";
$link_name3 = "Google3";

$link4 = "www.google.com4";
$link_name4 = "Google4";

$resources = array("$link"=>"$link_name","$link1"=>"$link_name1","$link2"=>"$link_name2","$link3"=>"$link_name3","$link4"=>"$link_name4");
foreach ($resources as $resources_link => $resources_name) {

echo "<a href=\"$resources_link\">$resources_name</a><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code modifying it a bit and can see all five links:

```
<?php

$resources = array(
"1"=>"A",
"2"=>"B",
"3"=>"C",
"4"=>"D",
"5"=>"E"
);

foreach ($resources as $resources_link => $resources_name) {

echo "<a href=\"$resources_link\">$resources_name</a><br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$link` is not define, if it is just a string, replace double quotes with single quotes.
like:

```
<?php

$resources = array(
'$link'=>'$link_name','$link1'=>'$link_name1','$link2'=>'$link_name2','$link3'=>'$link_name3','$link4'=>'$link_name4');

foreach ($resources as $resources_link => $resources_name) {

echo "<a href=\'$resources_link\'>$resources_name</a><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help everyone. Something was happening with the variables coming from the database and the array was skipping vales/listing in desc order for some reason. I ended up having to use a few if statements, but was able to get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the value of $link, $link_name, $link1, $link_name1, ... have special HTML characters. Try to change your loop to:

```
foreach ($resources as $resources_link => $resources_name) {
    echo "<a href=\"" . htmlentities($resources_link) . "\">" . htmlentities($resources_name) . "</a><br>";
}
```

htmlentities() will sanitize your text, so it will not break any HTML tags.